# Angular routing is not working with hostlistener/location popstate event(browser back event)

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, router

Angular routing is not working under hostlistener event. When user click on back button I want to navigate on specific page so I have used popstate hostlistener event but navigation is not happening for me.

Can someone help me please?

```
@HostListener('window:popstate')
  onPopState() {
    this.router.navigate(['user-list']);
  }
}
```

Comment: Suggest you use `Location` API, I faced a similar issue with `popstate` and was not able to resolve

Comment: Can you post your solution if it worked with the location @Navitas28?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround of setTimeout which works fine for me.

```
@HostListener('window:popstate')
  onPopState() {
      setTimeout(() => {
          this.router.navigate(['user-list']);
      });
  }
}
```